# $ sign is removed from the value in excel file

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, oledbdataadapter

I have an excel file which has a column called Price

Price

---

$ 200

$ 250

€ 50

I am using the following code to read data from my excel sheet into a DataTable.

```
OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", Connstr);
adp.Fill(dt);
```

When I check my DataTable in the price column I get the following output

Price

---

200

250

*null*

So what it does is it removes the $ sign and the cells with a € sign it completely ignores the data in that cell and I get no value in those cells.

Please suggest a fix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just add it back after `Fill`, it's just a string.

Comment: @LeiYang But how do I know what value was there in the cell with a currency sign other than a $ sign

Comment: Do the cells with the `$` actually contain the `$` or are they just formatted that way?

Comment: @AdarshRavi you should know the format(columns), otherwise what use after import the sheet?

Comment: $ sign is part of the format of the cell, it is not part of the value. You can ensure that by entering the cell or pressing on F2 and you may not see the $ sign inside it.

Comment: @Enigmativity They do contain $ sign and also € or any other currency symbol if present the cell comes out blank on fill

Comment: @ehh I just checked and you're right it's not part of the value but then I have to show the value with the $ sign on my grid after I import it. But my other issue to look at would be the blank values that I get with those associated with any other currency symbol

Comment: @AdarshRavi, I don't know how, you will need to google it on how to import data from excel to your C# and preserving the format.